# Virtualbox clipboard sharing

Tags: virtualbox, clipboard

I am using virtual box. I tried to enable clipboards bidirectional option, but when I copy anything from host file to guest, the paste option is not activated.

I have installed Guest Additions.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Can you please include some additional information, such as what your host and guest operating systems are and the version of VirtualBox you are using?

Comment: my host O.S. is windows 7 ultimate 32bit,and the guest is Windows XP sp3 but no way. my virtualbox version is 4.0.6

Answer (score 6):

If it's a file(s) or folder you're trying to copy on the shared clipboard, I don't think that type of clipboard data is supported.
When you copy a file, Windows doesn't write the entire file contents to the clipboard, it just writes a reference to the file. So it would make sense that you couldn't paste a file into a guest from the host's clipboard, since the guest doesn't know where that reference is pointing to.
Try copying some plain text between the guest and host - if everything's set up correctly you should have no problem doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen several issues with the guest additions not completely installing properly (particularly the video driver) if they are not installed while Windows XP has been booted in safe mode. I would suggest upgrading to the latest VirtualBox version if you haven't (you mentioned 4.0.6 but it isn't clear if you have that installed?) and then start your XP SP3 guest in safe mode and update/install the guest additions.